# PHP day and time if/elseif not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I put together a php to display a certain page based on whether or not we're open. test1.html is when we are open and test2.html is when we are closed. I saved the php as index.php.

When it executes, it only opens the else, which is the test2.html.

Can someone take a look at my code and see what's wrong with it?
Thanks!

```
<?php
 $day = date('N') ;
 $time = date('H:i') ;

 if (($day <= '4') && ($time >= '7:00') && ($time <= '19:30')) 
 {
    echo readfile ("test1.html");
 }
 elseif (($day == '5') && ($time >= '7:00') && ($time <= '18:30')) 
 {
    echo readfile ("test1.html");
 }
 elseif (($day == '6') && ($time >= '7:00') && ($time <= '17:30')) 
 {
    echo readfile ("test1.html");
 }
 else
 {
    echo readfile ("test2.html");
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are compared lexicographically, not numerically. So the string `10:00` is not greater than `7:00`, because the `1` is not greater than `7`. And `date('H')` returns times with a leading `0`, so in the morning the `$time` will be something like `08:21`, but that's not greater than `7:00`.

You need to include the leading `0` on the opening time, to make the comparisons work correctly.

```
if (($day <= '4') && ($time >= '07:00') && ($time <= '19:30'))
```